# Intellij Language Injection annotation @Language in Library does not work

Tags: html, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a small Test Lib which has a method like this:

```
assertHtml(String html) {}
```

I tried to add @Language Annotation from Intellij into the method definition. I want that my main project which has the lib as dependency has nice syntax coloring in the string with [language injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html#language_annotation)

So I added a @Language annotation:

```
assertHtml(@Language("HTML") String html) {}
```

This works fine as long as I have this method in the same project OR if I use an [includeBuild](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). I can see the syntax coloring immediately

If I build this lib and remove the `includeBuild` and use the test lib as a regular dependency, Intellij does not recognize the @Language Annotation anymore.

This is strange. Can I fix it and how?

Comment: hello, if possible can you please share a sample project that includes the not recognized language annotation. Please attach the project to the issue created at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA Thank you

Comment: I made two sample projects and opened an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-303529/LanguageInjection-does-not-work-if-annotation-is-in-project-from-dependency